# How to fetch Adwords campaign data from Google Analytics API?

Tags: analytics, google-ads-api

Hi i am using Google Analytics API and interested in extracting the AdWords Campaigning data which is available under OverAll Traffic>>Acquisition>>Adwords>>Campaigns and my query for the same is

```
return service.data().ga().get(
ids='ga:' + profile_id,
start_date=start_date, 
end_date=end_date,
metrics='ga:CPC,ga:transactions,ga:transactionsPerSession,ga:adCost,
ga:transactionRevenue,ga:bounceRate,ga:impressions,ga:adClicks,
ga:sessions',dimensions='ga:campaign,ga:deviceCategory',
sort ='-ga:adClicks',
segment = 'gaid::-1').execute()
```

but the above query is giving me the data related to all the campaigns but i only want to fetch the data that is related to Adwords Campaigns only.So, please help me in getting this done. I guess there should be some filter or any thing else by which we can extract the desired data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ga:sourceMedium==google / cpc
```

Use the above filter in your API request.

Or

Pull dimension  `ga:sourceMedium` and then filter `google / cpc` from the result set.

Comment: can you point me to the documentation for the same, i'm trying to get the data under OverAll Traffic>>Acquisition>>Campaigns>>All Campaigns

Answer (score 0):

```
auth: jwt,
ids: "ga:" + view_id,
"start-date": "YYYY-MM-DD",
"end-date": "YYYY-MM-DD",
metrics: "ga:adCost",
dimensions: "ga:campaign",
"start-index": "1",
"max-results": "1000"
```

You can do something like this